# Java 8 Httpclient 4.5 Multipart Post upload photo

Tags: java, java-8, apache-httpclient-4.x

How can I prepare that request with HttpClient? I'm using MultipartEntityBuilder, should I add every line seperately? Can somebody show me the way? I don't know if I should use ".addTextBody" or ".addPart". Thanks for all of your advices.

BTW. I know what variable"--Jd1TaCXiO7oTnFbdjk2l89xFc2JjUQ" or "dWSQUTuth0VhMI2Qy4oion5ETe74NzfL" is so don't worry :)

Here is the request's entity:

```
--Jd1TaCXiO7oTnFbdjk2l89xFc2JjUQ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_csrftoken"

dWSQUTuth0VhMI2Qy4oion5ETe74NzfL
--Jd1TaCXiO7oTnFbdjk2l89xFc2JjUQ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_uuid"

524465ae-0663-4fbd-9300-8109728a449e
--Jd1TaCXiO7oTnFbdjk2l89xFc2JjUQ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo"; filename="pending_media_1479922437148.jpg"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

SOME UNDREADABLE CHARACTERS HERE

--Jd1TaCXiO7oTnFbdjk2l89xFc2JjUQ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload_id"

1479922437121
--Jd1TaCXiO7oTnFbdjk2l89xFc2JjUQ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image_compression"

{"lib_name":"jt","lib_version":"1.3.0","quality":"86"}
--Jd1TaCXiO7oTnFbdjk2l89xFc2JjUQ--
```

ADDITIONAL QUESTION: content lenght of entity is 30874. In that situation, what kind of format should I use? Binary of the image has over one milion characters. What is octet-stream?

Comment: You can find some example code in the docs: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpmime/examples/org/apache/http/examples/entity/mime/ClientMultipartFormPost.java so yes, you use `addPart()` for every part.

Comment: Can you provide code of first part, please? I'm not sure about the way